# Using injectable for third party abstract class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, injectable

I have used package http in my project and thus, I have Client's instance (which comes from package http) as a dependency, which is an abstract class. So, how should I annotate with proper annotations?
In [injectable's documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable), there is information on [how to register third-party dependencies](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#registering-third-party-types) and [how to register abstract classes](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#binding-abstract-classes-to-implementations). But how can I register third-party abstract class?

This is my code

```
class TokenValueRemoteDataSourceImpl implements TokenValueRemoteDataSource {
  TokenValueRemoteDataSourceImpl(this.client);

  final http.Client client;

  @override
  Future<TokenValueModel> getAuthToken({
    required EmailAddress emailAddress,
    required Password password,
  }) async {
    final emailAddressString = emailAddress.getOrCrash();
    final passwordString = password.getOrCrash();
    const stringUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/token/';

    final response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(stringUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          'email': emailAddressString,
          'password': passwordString,
        },
      ),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return TokenValueModel.fromJson(
        json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
}
```

How should I write my register module for a third-party abstract class?

I did see this on injectable's documentation

```
@module  
abstract class RegisterModule {  
  @singleton  
  ThirdPartyType get thirdPartyType;  
  
  @prod  
  @Injectable(as: ThirdPartyAbstract)  
  ThirdPartyImpl get thirdPartyType;  
}
```

But I didn't understand what I should replace ThirdPartyImpl with in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to define an abstract class to inject your dependencies. So for in your case, to register a third-party class, you can use the same type without having an `abstract` and `concrete` class separately. See the below example of how to register the http `Client` class that is imported from the http package:

```dart
@module
abstract class YourModuleName {

  @lazySingleton // or @singleton 
  http.Client get httpClient => http.Client(); 
}
```

Then you can use the http `Client` anywhere using the global `GetIt` variable you have, like this:

`yourGetItVariableName.get<http.Client>();` or  `GetIt.I.get<http.Client>();`

Comment: I am having the same problem with `File` but am not having any luck with this implementation. I have tried this exact example and there is a compiler error on the most bottom left `http.Client()` saying:
`The class 'http.Client' doesn't have an unnamed constructor. Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'http.Client'.dartnew_with_undefined_constructor_default`