# Flutter Injectable Inject a Third Party Dependency

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, flutter-dependencies

I've been spinning my wheels for hours on the simple question of how to inject `http.Client` into a flutter class when using [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#registering-factories). They reference doing this in a module (as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70181489/using-injectable-for-third-party-abstract-class-in-flutter)), but I can't figure that out either.

This is my file (abstract and concrete classes):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:myapp_flutter/core/errors/exceptions.dart';
import 'package:myapp_flutter/data/models/sample_model.dart';

abstract class ISampleRemoteDataSource {

  /// Throws a [ServerException] for all error codes.
  Future<SampleModel> getSampleModel(String activityType);
}

@Injectable(as: ISampleRemoteDataSource)
class SampleRemoteDataSourceImpl extends ISampleRemoteDataSource {
  final http.Client client;
  final baseUrl = "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type=";
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

  SampleRemoteDataSourceImpl({@factoryParam required this.client});

  @override
  Future<SampleModel> getSampleModel(String activityType) async {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + activityType);
    GetIt.I.get<http.Client>();

    final response = await client.get(uri, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return SampleModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
}
```

I thought declaring it as a factory param in the constructor would do it, but I was wrong. Declaring the abstract class as a module doesn't do it (and seems very wrong, also). I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

First implement a register module file

```
@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
//add http client
@lazySingleton
http.Client get httpClient => http.Client();
}

class $RegisterModule extends RegisterModule {}
```

Then, after generating `injection.config.dart` file your http Client should be mentioned in `initGetIt` class

Answer (score 1):

annotate such 3rd party classes as a module.

```
@module
abstract class ServiceModule {
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseFirestore get getStore => FirebaseFirestore.instance;
}
```

you can access it as ,

```
FirebaseFirestore store = getIt<FirebaseFirestore>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register them as module as described below
https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#Registering-third-party-types

Comment: Thanks. I specifically linked to that in my post. As mentioned, I have attempted it, but have been unsuccessful. While their documentation does show that, I find it to be very insufficient at providing an working example of how to implement it. At least for my purposes, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem with the official documentation too. It shows how to define the module and the singleton, but how do you use it?